# Stack implementation in c++ with no maximum stack size limit

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I want to implement a stack in c++ whose stack size doesn't have any max limit.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000

class Stack
{
    int top;
public:
    int a[MAX]; //Maximum size of Stack

    Stack() { top = -1; }
    bool push(int x);
    int pop();
    bool isEmpty();
};
```

Is there any way to make MAX taking different values each time when an object is created?

Comment: There are ways of course. Just inspect / use `std::vector.`

Comment: What's wrong with `std::stack` ?

Comment: "doesn't have any max limit" and "to make MAX taking different values each time" is two different things. Which one are you really asking?

Comment: I just wanted to implement stack by my own. I am a beginner.

Comment: Look into how the `std::vector` class is implemented, and also allocating memory on the heap

Comment: @NickyC to make MAX taking different values so that each time an object is created it creates an stack of different maximum size.

Comment: Do you want a limitless stack or do you want to be able to specify MAX on creation? If the latter, you could use a template.

Answer (score 4):

The simple (and obvious) answer would be to use `std::vector`. Then your stack will grow without limit so no need for `MAX` at all.

If `std::vector` is not allowed for some reason another option would be to use a template

```
template <int MAX>
class Stack
{
    int top;
public:
    int a[MAX]; //Maximum size of Stack

    Stack() { top = -1; }
    bool push(int x);
    int pop();
    bool isEmpty();
};
```

In this solution `MAX` is a compile time constant. I.e. this is OK

```
Stack<10> s;
```

but this is not

```
int size = ...;
Stack<size> s;
```

The final (and worst) solution would be to do dynamic memory allocation using `new` and `delete`. Unless you been explcitly forbidden you should prefer `std::vector` to dynamic memory allocation.

BTW it's a **very** bad idea to make the elements of your stack public, as you have done with `a` above.

Comment: Maybe propose the alternative of using `std::array<int,MAX> a` instead of `int a[MAX]`, as it's a C++ question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `std::vector`:

In this implementation, the stack has virtually no limit. You can pass a hint size in the constructor just to preallocate some space, so that it's faster to fill the stack. But then if you go beyond this limit, `std::vector` will automatically grow its storage:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

class Stack
{
    std::vector<int> stack;
public:

    Stack(std::size_t size = 1000) {
        // reserving the underlying storage space makes the stack faster
        // to fill because no memory reallocation is neeeded
        // for the 'size' first elements.
        stack.reserve(size);
    }

    // doesn't return a bool anymore because every push is supposed to succeed
    // (or fail with an exception if no more memory is available)
    void push(int x) {
        // 'stack' will grow the underlying storage space if needed
        stack.push_back(x);
    }
    int pop() {
        assert(!stack.empty());
        auto res = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        return res;
    }
    bool isEmpty() {
        return stack.empty();
    }
};
```